# How to get JUnit5's TestInstance's LifeCycle in Spring's TestExectionListener?

Tags: java, spring, junit5, spring-test

Is there any way to get [TestInstance.LifeCycle](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestInstance.Lifecycle.html)  (PER_CLASS or PER_METHOD) in SpringTest's [TestExecutionListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestExecutionListener.html) ?

For example , in method `afterTestMethod(TestContext testContext)` , how to get current TestInstance's LifeCycle ?

I looked into TestContext code but seems no related API.

Then, I tried to traverse `testContext.getTextClass().getDeclaredAnnotations()` , but I think it is not sufficient, as JUnit5 supports declaring default lifecycle in properties or system environment.

Is there any other way to achieve this ? Thanks.

Comment: Please describe your use case. In other words, why do you need the test instance lifecycle in a Spring `TestExecutionListener`?

Comment: @SamBrannen I want to process something in `afterTestClass` and `afterTestMethod` depending on PER_CLASS or PER_METHOD

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot access JUnit Jupiter APIs or features such as the test instance lifecycle from a Spring `TestExecutionListener`.

The Spring `TestExecutionListener` and `TestContext` APIs are agnostic of the underlying testing framework (e.g., JUnit, TestNG, etc.).

If you need access to JUnit-specific features, you might consider implementing a JUnit Jupiter `Extension` instead of a Spring `TestExecutionListener`. Note that a Spring `TestExecutionListener` can obtain access the Spring `ApplicationContext` via `SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(ExtensionContext)`.

Comment: I tried to implement junit5's `AfterEachCallback` in my custom ExecitionListener : `MyExecutionListener extends AbstractTestExecutionListner implements AfterEachCallback` , but it seems spring's AbstractTestExecutionListner swallows junit5's callback and AfterEachCallback is not called .  Is there any way to solve this ?